# Django Photologue XML Error

Tags: python, html, xml, django, photologue

Does someone know why I get an `XML-Error` when I try to open a picture via Django-Photologue?
Unfortunately the Error message is in German:

```
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: nicht wohlgeformt
Adresse: http://example.com/photologue/photo/name_of_photo/
Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 1:
```

Which Roughly translates to:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Address: http://example.com/photologue/photo/name_of_photo/
Line no. 1, column 1:
```

before it said instead of something like `<!Doctype html>` so I assume it has something to do with a certain template of photologue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't speak German :-) but it looks like the picture is at domain 'example.com'. Try setting a valid domain name?

Comment: How do I set this valid domain name? Do I have to change something with `django.contrib.sites`?

Comment: Yes, that's right - set a valid domain name in `django.contrib.sites`.
Sorry for lack of clarity in my earlier comment.